# Performance of a sql query on an indexed key vs primary key

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a mysql innodb table -

```
create table data (
    `sha256` CHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    'created` TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    <some other fields>
    PRIMARY KEY (`sha256`),
)
```

One of the slowest queries in mysqld_slow_query is

```
select * from data where created between "2013-02-01" and "2013-03-01";
```

In order to improve the execution of this query I have two option:

Option 1: Add an index on created

Option 2: Make ('created', 'sha256') the primary key, and add an index on sha256.

The thinking here is that when we select a large number of rows, like data collected in a month, I'd like to reduce the number of the B-tree blocks that are accessed. If we access these records via an index (Option 1), we'd still end up potentially accessing a different block for each record. Instead, if we store the records sorted by timestamp as the primary/clustered key(option 2), we'll find large number of records in the same B-tree block and this will reduce the disk reads.

But for some reason, while Option 1 improves performance, Option 2 doesn't improve it as much.
Any ideas why? And any other suggestions? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Is this a MyISAM or InnoDB table?

Comment: Since when does mysql allow you to use `{` in `CREATE TABLE` commands?

Comment: @G_Nugget InnoDB. Barmar fixed the parenthesis

Comment: @fvu I don't think the question is about the index on the unrelated field, it's about putting an index on `created` versus making `(created, sha256)` the primary key.

Comment: Adding an index on `created` would most definitely speed up the query a lot. The second option does not make any sense to me.

Comment: @decden Isn't there an index on the prefix of a composite primary key?

Comment: Composite keys could work in theory (if the keys are indexed in the right order for your query, i.e. `created` first), but in practice, they cannot index your query efficiently. Furthermore a composite index usually requires more memory (as it stores more data) and this may impact performance as well.

Comment: The choices are - an additional index on created, or make create the primary key. I think that the primary key is used as the key in the B-tree that stores the data. So, all the data is actually sorted by it. Now, when we query for large number of sequential rows, we'd hit fewer b-tree blocks.

Comment: @Barmar indeed - I misread the question, sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 1):

InnoDB is particularly sensitive to large primary keys since it uses clustered primary indexes and a `CHAR(64)` makes for a very large primary key.  I would suggest that you add an `AUTOINCREMENT` id column as the primary key and give `sha256` a unique index.  Those along with an index on `created` should help performance all around.  Look-ups on `sha256` will be slightly slower, but everything else will be faster.  Inserts will also be faster since the data will never need to be shifted around by the random values of `sha256`.

I'm not completely sure why the single index would have been much faster, but it probably has to do with the composite index being so large even though it is a clustered index.

Comment: Yes, I know primary key CHAR(64) is a bad idea, and for the interim, I'd either use HEX or a subset of the char(64). But that's a separate issue. Question is - why is index(`created`) better than primary key(`created`) for this particular query which will return a large number of rows.